# Apache NiFi s3 File movement using Wait and Notify Processor

Tags: amazon-s3, apache-nifi

I have a NiFi flow that is fetching files from an s3 bucket. The files are processed using "ExecuteScript" and "UpdateAttribute" processors and then put into a local drive after modification using the "PutFile" processor.

I need to move the original file in the s3 bucket to another "archive" bucket. This needs to happen after the "PutFile" has run successfully. If any of the processors fail, the file needs to be transferred to another s3 "failed" bucket.
I tried using the Wait and Notify processor to achieve this, but the Wait processor seems to have the modified files in the queue and not the original one.

In the Wait/Notify, I am using ${uuid} as the Release Signal Identifier.

Flow Image here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/k8Kqk.png

Is there any other better way to achieve this?
Any tips, suggestions or help appreciated! Thanks in advance.
P.S New to NiFi entirely, so I might have missed something obvious, but Google did not help me much with this.

Comment: `Wait-Notify` is right approach, have a look at this article to understand wait notify implementation - http://ijokarumawak.github.io/nifi/2017/02/02/nifi-notify-batch/ (even you can import template as well)

Comment: @VikramsinhShinde Thanks! The article helped. I created and used a new property called ${source.uuid} as the release signal identifier as mentioned in the article that sends the original file. Works well in my setup.